# How can I maintain state in a yowsup python application

Tags: python

I want to implement a USSD like application based on yowsup. Its like a question and answer like app.
Example:

Me: REPORT ----- > Yowsup number

Yowsup app: NAME?

ME: [my name]

Yowsup app: AGE?

ME: [age]

etc

I would like the app to gather all variables before doing a database insert. I would like to know how to implement this
 I was thinking of creating a global list to hold the data before inserting. Is this good programming practice?

Comment: the global list i mentioned. but i dont know if that would scale under high message traffic from whatsapp is it good python programming practice to do so?

Comment: It would be much easier to understand your question if you wrote some code or pseudocode to describe your proposed design in the question.